# Receiving items in onNext() after calling dispose() in RxJava

Tags: kotlin, observable, rx-java2, dispose

This is what I read about `dispose()` [here](https://medium.com/@vanniktech/rxjava-2-disposable-under-the-hood-f842d2373e64):

> In a nutshell, when the Disposable (which is implemented by the
>   TestObserver) gets disposed, the Observer (also TestObserver) will no
>   longer receive values from the Observable.

Here is my code:

```
private fun createObservableWithDisposable() {
    Observable
            .create { e: ObservableEmitter<String> ->
                val worker = Schedulers.io().createWorker()
                e.setDisposable(worker)
                worker.schedule {
                    for (i in 1..5) {
                        if (i == 3) {
                            worker.dispose()
                            // https://medium.com/@vanniktech/rxjava-2-disposable-under-the-hood-f842d2373e64
                            // After calling dispose(), the subscriber no longer receives items passed in OnNext().
                            // But it doesn't work in my code
                        }
                        e.onNext("Event $i on thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                    }
                }
            }
            .subscribe(
                    { s ->
                        Log.d(TAG, "createObservableWithDisposable onNext msg=$s")
                    },
                    { e ->
                        Log.d(TAG, "createObservableWithDisposable", e)
                    },
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "createObservableWithDisposable onComplete")
                    }
            )
}
```

And this is what I see in Logcat:

```
2019-02-25 08:10:53.414 12071-12101/ru.sample D/RxJavaSamples: createObservableWithDisposable onNext msg=Event 1 on thread RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2019-02-25 08:10:53.414 12071-12101/ru.sample D/RxJavaSamples: createObservableWithDisposable onNext msg=Event 2 on thread RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2019-02-25 08:10:53.414 12071-12101/ru.sample D/RxJavaSamples: createObservableWithDisposable onNext msg=Event 3 on thread RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2019-02-25 08:10:53.414 12071-12101/ru.sample D/RxJavaSamples: createObservableWithDisposable onNext msg=Event 4 on thread RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
2019-02-25 08:10:53.414 12071-12101/ru.sample D/RxJavaSamples: createObservableWithDisposable onNext msg=Event 5 on thread RxCachedThreadScheduler-1
```

I expected to see only the first two emissions. I.e., I thought that after calling `dispose()` `onNext()` won't be called.

Comment: With `create`, you have to cooperate with the sequence. If you know you want to stop from within the loop, stop onNexting more items and `break` out. Use `emitter.isDisposed` to detect if the consumer wants to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you disposed worker which had been providing items, not subscriber.

To stop receiving items, try to

```
val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    compositeDisposable.add(
            Observable
                    .create { e: ObservableEmitter<String> ->
                        val worker = Schedulers.io().createWorker()
                        e.setDisposable(worker)
                        worker.schedule {
                            for (i in 1..5) {
                                if (i == 3) {
                                    compositeDisposable.dispose() //changed here
                                }
                                e.onNext("Event $i on thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    .subscribe(
                            { s ->
                                Log.d(TAG, "createObservableWithDisposable onNext msg=$s")
                            },
                            { e ->
                                Log.d(TAG, "createObservableWithDisposable", e)
                            },
                            {
                                Log.d(TAG, "createObservableWithDisposable onComplete")
                            }

                    )
    )
```

Comment: could you expand more about what happens when I dispose worker?

Comment: @TrầnĐứcTâm It would let worker's task queue to be cleared. So current running task still alive, until emit 5th item. if you want to know how it works exactly, you could check the `IoScheduler.java` from `package io.reactivex.internal.schedulers`